# How to Initialize a Point Array?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing some Win32 program. and I meet a problem.
I define an array of Point,just like this:

```
   POINT points[3];
```

and now I want to Initialize it, and I know this is illegal

```
   POINT points[3] = { (295,295),(200,200),(400,500) };
```

so I need the correct way.

Comment: try POINT points[3] = { {295,295},{200,200},{400,500} };

Comment: You don't really need the 3.  Just let the computer do the counting for you.

Comment: @user3116182: Illegal? It doesn't do what you apparently want it to do, but it is certainly not illegal. The code will compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply as

```
POINT points[3] = { 295, 295, 200, 200, 400, 500 };
```

but a safer thing to do would be this

```
POINT points[3] = { { 295, 295 }, { 200, 200 }, { 400, 500 } };
```

The amusing part is that what you originally wrote is not illegal (where did you get that idea?). The `()` you used inside your initializer will cause the inner `,` to be interpreted as *comma operator*. For example, expression `(400, 500)` evaluates to `500`. That means that your original initializer is actually treated as

```
POINT points[3] = { 295, 200, 500 };
```

which is in turn equivalent to

```
POINT points[3] = { { 295, 200 }, { 500, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
```

It doesn't do what you want it to do, but it is certainly not illegal.

Comment: nice answer. I am sorry that my expression is not rigorous.

Comment: Can you tell me more about inner comma operator, such as its source code. @AndreyT

Comment: @user3116182: Comma operator in your original code case is a built-in operator, part of core C++ language. It has no "source code". There's plenty of info about it on the Net (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments:

```
POINT points[] = {{295,295}, {200,200}, {400,500}};
```